# The remote server returned an error: (421) Service not available, closing control connection

Tags: c#, ftp

I am running this code for alot of files to transfer locally to another server via ftp. The problem is I am periodically getting the error The remote server returned an error: (421) Service not available, closing control connection. Is there a problem with the code, a better way to transfer the files that is quicker more efficient. All the files need to be transfered so I was thinking a while loop and catching the error until all files in the folder have transfered. It is a periodic error I am getting:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request =
            (FtpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", Host, destinationPath,
                    file.Name));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        /* 20 mins timeout */
        request.Timeout = 1200000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1200000;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);

        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }

        //using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        //{

        //}

        if (deleteSourcePath)
        {
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //  Log.Warn("Error Moving Images", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that one can judge the quality of a code snippet by the number of exception-eating `catch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Call Close on the the FtpWebResponse object. That will release the associated port.

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
// ...
finally
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```